# Child window inform calling window when closed

Tags: wpf, window

I have a parent window create a child window.  When the child window closes, I want to have the parent window receive notification so that it can be refreshed.  The child window cannot be modal.  The user needs to be able to interact with the rest of the application.

Comment: Pass a reference to the parent in the constructor.  Have the child call a method on the partent to notify it is shutting down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the parent window create a handler for the [`Closed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) on the child window object. When the child window is closed, your handler will be called and the parent window will be notified.

Comment: but on refreshing any child window the object is null inside the array. But the child window remains same. Then how can we update the array?